# Linq issues, joining two tables and a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Ok, I could need some help as I really suck at linq!

This collection contains x number of time slot DTO's for a given day.

```
List<TimeslotDto> timeSlots = new List<TimeslotDto>();
```

The **TimeslotDto** contains a DateTime **SlotStart** property and a bool **IsReserved**. This collection works, it contains the number of timeslots that I want. Fine.

Now to my problem. I want to use this collection in a linq query.
I have two tables,"**Staff**" and "**Timeslots**"(well actually three, but if I get help with this i might be able to add the last table to the query myself)

The "**Timeslots**" table contains:

- StaffId(FK)
- TimeslotId(PK)
- SlotStart
- ActivityId(FK the third table).

The "**Staff**" table contains:

- StaffId(PK)
- Navigation property for Timeslots

Based on this...I want to produce a result that for each staff member has a list of **timeSlots** and for those slots in the collection that has the same date in the Timeslots table the **IsReserved** prop should be set to true.

So the timeSlots collection contains all possible slots for any given day.
The Timeslots table contains reservations. I want to x-check the collections to find reservations for each staff member.

Thanks in advance!

If someone has a really good tutorial on mastering linq, please share it.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want to set IsReserved property to true on all timeslots which have the same SlotStart?

Comment: Yes, and for each staff member. Timeslots table has a StaffId prop but the timeSlot colletion does not.

Comment: Is the `timeSlots` collection based on a database table?

Comment: No it's not, I am calculating the possible time slots for any given day, instead of having them stored in a table. Maybe my query could be done i two steps. First assign the timeSlot collection for each staff. And then in another query update the slots in the collection for each staff member...but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Contains` statement for this:

```
var query = timeSlots.Where(sl => TimeSlots.Where(t => t.StaffId == staffId)
                                           .Select(t => t.SlotStart)
                                           .Contains(sl.SlotStart));
```

This is (slightly) better scalable if `timeSlots` only contains the time slots for that particular staff.

In query syntax this would look like

```
var query = from sl in timeSlots
            where (from t in TimeSlots
                   where t.StaffId == staffId
                   select(t => t.SlotStart))
                  .Contains(sl.SlotStart);
```

Another option is to get the `TimeSlots` in memory and join with `timeSlots`. (You can't join local collections with LINQ to a SQL backend.)

```
from sl in timeSlots
join t in TimeSlots.Where(x => x.StaffId == staffId)
                   .AsEnumerable() // Switch to memory
    on ts.SlotStart equals t.SlotStart
```

again assuming that `timeSlots` is per staff.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. How does this look with query syntax?

Comment: I think I just learnt that the hard way, that local collections can't be joined that way. In the collection I don't have the StaffId, only the StartSlot. I need to somehow add the Timeslots from table to memory. I am not able to complete this with your example.

Comment: Or maybe add the "local" timeslots to Staff objects and set a StaffId at the same time and then make a join.